# IllegalArgumentException: BigQueryConnectorException$InvalidSchemaException: Destination table's schema is not compatible with dataframe's schema

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr, google-cloud-dataproc

We are unable to write data into big query. facing below issue.
Big query connector jar: spark-3.4-bigquery-0.33.0.jar

ERROR Client: Application diagnostics message: User class threw exception: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:760)
Caused by: com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1. [Guice/ErrorInCustomProvider]: IllegalArgumentException: BigQueryConnectorException$InvalidSchemaException: Destination table's schema is not compatible with dataframe's schema
   at BigQueryDataSourceWriterModule.provideDirectDataSourceWriterContext(BigQueryDataSourceWriterModule.java:61)
   while locating BigQueryDirectDataSourceWriterContext

Code snippet:
We used below code snippet.
System.setProperty("GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT", "");
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("BigQuerySparkApp").getOrCreate();

```
    Dataset<Row> csvData = 
    
spark.read().format("csv").option("inferSchema","true").option("header", 
  "true").load("csv");
    String projectID = "";
    String datasetID = "";
    String tableID = "communication_master";
    String tableFullName = projectID + ":" + datasetID + "." + tableID;
    csvData.write().format("bigquery")
    .option("writeMethod", "direct")
    .option("table", tableFullName)
    .option("schema", "")
    .option("credentials", "")
    .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite) .save();
    spark.stop();
```

Comment: The error is about mismatch between schemas, have you compared the two?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi Dagang, We are trying only one column with String type from csv to BigQuery.

Comment: We used below code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

We all need to fix issues but keep in mind that some of them are a bit hidden among others.

This issue is documented on the [Spark Big Query Connector Github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector/issues/658). It seems to be an internal issue. I'm inferring this because you didn't provide any code of what is causing it.